# c# Как убрать табличку в вин 8 при запуске (недовереный источник)

Tags: c#

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Windows.Forms;

internal class Zone
{
    public static void WriteAlternateStream(string path, string text)
    {
        const int GENERIC_WRITE = 1073741824;
        const int FILE_SHARE_WRITE = 2;
        const int OPEN_ALWAYS = 4;
        var stream = CreateFileW(path, GENERIC_WRITE, FILE_SHARE_WRITE, IntPtr.Zero, OPEN_ALWAYS, 0, IntPtr.Zero);
        using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(stream, FileAccess.Write))
        {
            using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(fs))
            {
                sw.Write(text);
            }
        }
    }
    public static void Id()
    {
        var x = Application.ExecutablePath + ":Zone.Identifier";
        WriteAlternateStream(x, "[ZoneTransfer]\r\nZoneId=3");
    }
    # region Imports
    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", EntryPoint = "CreateFileW")]
    public static extern System.IntPtr CreateFileW(
        [InAttribute()] [MarshalAsAttribute(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] string lpFileName,
        uint dwDesiredAccess,
        uint dwShareMode,
        [InAttribute()] IntPtr lpSecurityAttributes,
        uint dwCreationDisposition,
        uint dwFlagsAndAttributes,
        [InAttribute()] IntPtr hTemplateFile
    );
    #endregion
}
```

Крч при запуске проги, табличка предупреждает пользователя что файл из интернета!

Comment: А откуда файл? Ругается на саму программу или скачиваемые ею файлы?

Comment: Ну когда сам файл запускаешь

Comment: В винде тупо открыть свойства и нажать "разблокировать" - не вариант? Признак проставляется только браузерами, насколько помню, а потому операция врядли должна быть проблемой.

Comment: Юсеры туповатые, нужно программно!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6375373/3768545 - вот в принципе простой рабочий вариант. Проверьте, есть шанс что сама программа после запуска себя поправить не сможет.